# Equally subset data based on a condition and across country/industry in R

Tags: r

I have some data and I am trying to reduce the size of but based on a number of conditions.

I am looking to (randomly) select a fixed set of observations.

Take `30` observations which has the `status` of `0` and `30` observations which has the `status` of `1`. Doing this for each of the `4` sectors and each of the `10` regions.

So I am trying in the end to have a equally weighted data set of 30 * 2 * 4 * 10 observations. Where the 2 is the combination of the `status 0/1`. So each region and sector will have `30` 1´s and 30 0´s. So region 1 Construction will be 30 for status 1 and status 0. Region 1 Manufacturing will have 30 for status 1, 30 for status 0. etc.

Does this make sense?

EDIT: As @Dan Hall pointed out, do not use the number `30`. Use instead `3` or `4` - a number low enough that there will be an intersect of `0`´s and `1`´s in both the `sector` and `region`.

Also I cut down the number of `regions` from `10` to `3`, to increase the likelihood that observations will overlap.

```
structure(list(sector = c("Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", "Construction", 
"Manufacturing", "Services", "Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Wholesale_retailtrade", "Construction", "Services", "Construction", 
"Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Manufacturing", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Manufacturing", 
"Construction", "Wholesale_retailtrade", "Services", "Services", 
"Manufacturing", "Construction", "Construction", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Construction", "Construction", "Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Services", "Manufacturing", "Services", "Services", "Construction", 
"Services", "Services", "Manufacturing", "Construction", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Construction", "Wholesale_retailtrade", "Construction", "Construction", 
"Wholesale_retailtrade", "Construction", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", "Services", "Wholesale_retailtrade", 
"Services", "Services", "Construction", "Services", "Services", 
"Wholesale_retailtrade"), Region.in.country.id = c(1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
2L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L), status = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0), EBIT.TA = c(-0.234432635519391, 
-0.884337466274593, -0.00446559204081373, 0.11109107677028, -0.137203773525798, 
-0.582114677880617, -3.04252763094666, 0.113157822682219, -0.0255533180037229, 
-0.191945591325174, -0.273949107908537, 0.435398668004486, -2.75971618056051, 
0.00912639083178201, -0.0386627754065697, -0.018235399636112, 
-0.701299939137125, 0.0191819361175666, -0.801677105519484, -0.402194475974272, 
-0.124125227730062, 0.143020458476649, -0.601186271451194, 0.0163269364787831, 
5.09955167591238, -0.048325913947516, -0.0663917552037046, 0.0731554272767197, 
0.0541412252436794, -0.106653395605237, -1.91212516082209, 0.013895114729996, 
-0.0408852749206468, -1.04242876103153, 0.0640363205154842, 0.0317654085334603, 
-2.88205521472393, -0.0927206503854049, -0.418083504654432, 0.0587929389508339, 
-0.236993693848064, -0.363597190828615, -0.231025373317332, 0.00383173853820317, 
0.133672148114335, -0.0375825925943346, -0.0228362974641541, 
-0.145459032108046, -0.0244615574681876, NA, -0.0798573270032175, 
0.135507850559964, -0.0123281590551136, 0.00531719245854234, 
-1.22380405663988, -1.10131852879944, -0.00328951597828484, -0.0182153428113931, 
-8.66283275187364, -0.00107847713293943), SALES.TA = c(2.95045954435647, 
1.07456391911965, NA, 1.93526904477577, 0.00271354354050435, 
2.07767913655237, 11.9303700144161, 1.11755699760875, NA, 0.0788133580177983, 
2.42886718423909, 1.68097759893, 1.51308564501177, 0.335061014804079, 
0.721348744673176, 2.07152192296851, 1.30288811566243, 2.0590408006413, 
1.41743431942698, 19.7635262958759, 0.46867460706241, 1.75475674493509, 
0.481387726379507, 0.859201794216593, 17.4033586556749, 3.64655842727608, 
0.0861052293275039, 0.559100618136786, 0.83951869426017, 0.03449746792523, 
2.27258931811434, NA, 2.74200566426626, 1.99830792578139, 1.60128272244184, 
0.723342520813072, 3.48353783231084, 0.016439857192032, 5.95890794679792, 
1.05006899714593, 0.617495446497135, 4.96325247012043, 1.61640701342419, 
NA, 1.46503684554249, 1.20422580307878, 0.000442610673849077, 
3.64908933876218, 0.00147908687833738, NA, 0.269961444802266, 
3.83615117286978, 1.26314203617084, 0.467669177880749, NA, 2.07772380291464, 
NA, NA, 0.00206821855627459, 0.769551579722081)), .Names = c("sector", 
"Region.in.country.id", "status", "EBIT.TA", "SALES.TA"), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I must be misunderstanding your question, because you don't have 30 observations with a status of 1. You only have 5. So you can't randomly select 30 unique observations from those 5.

Comment: My appologies! This is just a small sample of the data, so perhaps set the number of observations to `3` ? I can always increase the number later on.

Comment: I see your point! I will remove half of the `country.id` observations and re-upload a dput

Comment: Okay, I have now put more 0`s and 1`s in the status column and reduced the number of countries. So there should be overlapping 1`s and 0`s in industry/country.

Comment: Now there is 27, 1`s in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
df %>%
  group_by(sector, Region.in.country.id, status) %>%
  sample_n(30)
```

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! I should really take some sort of course on the dplyr package...

Comment: In case you need proportional sampling, try `dplyr::sample_frac()`.